# Can I split SQLite file and recreate/merge back inside Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have large sqlite Dabase file I read this [post](http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2010/mar/13/deploying-android-apps-with-large-databases/) I am not able to merge back the sqlite database..

tried using .sqlite and .db both files.

there are some difference between database files..  i.e. original and after merge file.

recreated file doesn't open..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you definately can. But there are some moments you have to look into. Check out the working example in [my article](http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/2011/02/android-sqlite-crud-methods-2/) I had the same issue and actually made it work. The negative side is that you will never get rid of "unused" split-files after you merge them, because of the readable-only android file system and /assets folder politics

Comment: You are copying database to the data/data/ folder.. what I want is to split database file in to 2 or more.. and then merge it to one inside.. data/data folder

Comment: I saw that you have sample on the website.. but the source code from your website is not the same..

Comment: The key is the following: you first have to open a readable (or writeable ) copy of your database and then merge it with your splits, meaning that you will have to set the path of output stream to the newly created database.

Comment: Your account has been suspended, from where shall I get the Tutorial?

Comment: Hello you Account has been suspend buddy, helpout to provide the demo.